# Exec into Pods/containers in kubernetes/Docker, created from images that does not contain bash pre-installed

Tags: docker, ssh, kubernetes, alpine-linux

I'm trying to exec into haproxy-ingress pod created from [this](https://quay.io/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress) image, with this command:

`kubectl -n kube-system exec -it haproxy-ingress-4122301161-bcd94 /bin/bash`

Then I get this message

> rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime
>   error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process
>   caused \"exec: \\"/bin/bash\\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or
>   directory\"\n"

Is there a way to exec into a container that is created using an image that does not have bash pre-installed?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's not that uncommon for container not to have bash available. Often you will find that when bash is not there, `/bin/sh` still is, as is the case for the image you mention. Thus using `kubectl -n kube-system exec -it haproxy-ingress-4122301161-bcd94 /bin/sh` should suffice.

That aside, please mind for sake of clarity, you do not SSH into container, you execute a process within it.

Answer (score -2):

```
kubectl debug -n kube-system -it haproxy-ingress-4122301161-bcd94 --target=your_container_name --image=ubuntu
```